# Editing the output of AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, post, aws-lambda

Having a question regarding error handling in AWS Lambda using Python.

Right now when error happens(testing via postman, for example) I've got the typical following one:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Y contains previously unseen labels: ''",
    "errorType": "ValueError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 81, in lambda_handler\n    X['dis'] = du.transform(X.dis)\n",
        "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py\", line 273, in transform\n    _, y = _encode(y, uniques=self.classes_, encode=True)\n",
    ]
}
```

Have couple of questions:

- how can I disable the stacktrace of the output that it won't be displayed when queried
- how the http error code can be added to the output?

Many thanks!

Comment: Postman is calling API gateway?

Comment: yes, calling API gateway

Comment: interesting. How is lambda function written? Maybe it provides that output?. Generally if lambda errors out, api gateway is not going to report such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it using API Gateway Method Response for defining http type errors and Integration Response with Lambda Regex for processing `errorMessage`. After redeployment the API Gateway endpoint, you can receive new error message when sending 'bad' requests